# nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

For some reason JPA is giving me an error saying:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class 
path resource 

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: 
Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

I simply set up JPA and my Oracle DB in my **application.properties** like so:

## Oracle database setup

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@999.999.999.999:1521:d9SID
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.profiles.active=oracle
```

## JPA setup

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect


server.port = 4000
```

pom file:

```
  <name>backend</name>
    <description>Demo project in Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I did not see any conflicts in my mvn:tree and from my understanding you can create a datasource in `application.properties`.

--------------------UPDATE 1------------------------

Full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.jrLockAndRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.request.RequestDemoApplication.main(RequestDemoApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.__createEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.__createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: any exception has a stack trace which also shows nested exceptions; yours is no exception to that rule. Perhaps show it ... all

Comment: @NeilStockton please see update one.

Comment: _Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect] as strategy_ ... so your "dialect" name is wrong. Clearly other JPA providers can auto-detect what RDBMS is in use, but yours seems to need to be told?!

Comment: @NeilStockton I found out `Oracle10gDialect` will work for 10 and 11 and it got rid of my error. Now I have a whole new error: `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory` and `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit` never even seen those before.

Comment: internet search has

Comment: @NeilStockton I think I figured it out. I had `ojdbc7.jar` when I need `ojdbc6.jar`. So I deleted it and I tried to download `ojdbc6.jar' by using the following command and it didn't work `mvn install:install-file -Dfile={/home/keystone/Desktop/oracle_jars/ojdbc6.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle
` and it said the file does not exist.

Comment: You may want to review this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02391_exceeded_silultaneous_sessions_user_limit.htm